# Layer 7 path based routing to Docker containers without Docker Enterprise

Tags: docker, reverse-proxy, docker-swarm

The Docker EE docs state you can use their built in load balancer to do path based routing: 
https://docs.docker.com/ee/ucp/interlock/usage/context/

I would love to use this for our local devs to have a local container cluster to develop against since a lot of our apps are using host paths to route each service.

My original solution was to add another container to the compose service that would just be an nginx proxy doing path based routing, but then I stumbled on that Docker EE functionality.

**Is there anything similar to that functionality without using Docker EE** or should I stick with just using an nginx reverse proxy container?

EDIT: I should clarify, in our release environments, I use an ALB with AWS. This is for local dev workstations.

Answer (score 3):

The Docker EE functionality is just them wrapping automation around an [interlock](https://github.com/ehazlett/interlock) container, which itself runs nginx I think.  I recommend you just use nginx locally in your compose file, or better yet, use [traefik](https://traefik.io/), which is purpose-built for this exact purpose.